# handling activites and layouts android

Tags: android

I have 2 activities.

In first activity there are some text fields and two buttons. In text fields I'm entering some data, and by clicking the first button I'm calling second activity that displays a ListView with checkboxes.

And from second activity after clicking a button over there I'm calling the first activity again. But by the time I move to that page, all data that have been entered earlier have disappeared.

I would need that data to reside even if I move back and forward between two activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Activity2, when clicking Button to go to Activity1
Simply on `button.onClickListener`
Add `this.finish();`

And don't explicitly call the Activity1.

So your data wont be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `activity2` with `startActivityForResult` method and from the `activity2` when the button is clicked just call `setResult()` followed by `finish` and handle `onActivityResult` event in `activity1`, for more  information you can refer this [`Android startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and related post [`Handling result`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)